# IMB MQ: Getting message from queue before it leaves it. Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

For example, I have a queue manager with two queues. I put message to **Q1** than is goes to another queue **Q2**. And in **Q1** my message get some new things in it's body, like unique ID.

So the question is Can I somehow using Java get my message from **Q1** before it goes to **Q2** ? Or at least get some info about it.

Actually this example is very simplified and I just want to know is it possible to get message before it leaves the queue.

**Update:**

I also have a message broker with some logic. My queue manager and it's queues are local. **Q2** is a transmission queue, from which message is send to adapter. So I'm interesting in browsing my message which I put in **Q1** before it goes to adapter or **Q2**. Can I make it with Java classes or JMS without changing message flow triggers and handlers or changing adapter source code?

Comment: Is Q1 a QREMOTE and Q2 a QLOCAL with USAGE(XMITQ)?  Or is Q1 a QALIAS and Q2 a QLOCAL?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.  Messages in a local queue do not magically move from one queue to another queue.  You should update your question and be more precise on what type of queues you are using.

Is Q1 a cluster or remote queue?